# Exclude values in one column from another column in excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

COUNTIF function given in this link [CLICK](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4076-excel-exclude-one-list-from-another.html) is working for me but I want exact match. For example in below set this function is matching aefrd and aefrdwe which I don't want. It shouldn't match. What change should I make in this formula for exact match?

I'm using same formula as mentioned in link

=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$6,A2)

Please suggest.

**ColA**
aefrd

tyu

asd

**ColB**

aefrdwe

tyu

cvbn

qasdf

Comment: @BigBen It's done. Please check now

Comment: That should only count exact matches (well, case insensitive). No repro based on what you've provided.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen. I think that worked out

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem either. The `COUNTIF` is also case-sensitive, so even `afrdwe` and `AFRD` don't get counted.

Comment: @OverflowStacker - `COUNTIF` is actually not case sensitive... see the [docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34).